# Requiring OS X >= Lion for an application

Tags: c++, macos

One of the open source software I'm contributing to has recently started using features that are only available on OS X 10.7 and later. We'd like to detect at startup time (or preferably before the program is even started, if some DMG metadata allows for that) if a user is using an older version of OS X and display a message telling him to upgrade his OS (or use an older version of our software).

What is the best way to do this? I'm not an OS X developer so please keep it as simple as possible :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using methods in the C std library. This question explains how [Getting the OS version in Mac OS X using standard C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969485/getting-the-os-version-in-mac-os-x-using-standard-c)

As mentioned in the comments this was deprecated in 10.8. This question explains a work around for the time being [How do I determine the OS version at runtime in OS X or iOS (without using Gestalt)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072804/mac-os-x-10-8-replacement-for-gestalt-for-testing-os-version-at-runtime)

Comment: Gestalt has been deprecated starting from OS X 10.8 from what I read on the internet. It does not seem like the right way to go for new code. Any better way to do that?

Comment: @PierreBourdon there is a work around. I'm posting a link to another question which explains it.